# Java and Regex, get a substring which matches

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to match the following pattern:

```
[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[BL]
```

and apply the pattern to this string:

```
123-456-L-234
```

which should become

```
123-456-L.
```

Here's my code:

```
HelperRegex{
..
final static Pattern KEY = Pattern.compile("\\d*-\\d*-[BL]");

    public static String matchKey(String key) {
        return KEY.matcher(key).toMatchResult().group(0);
    }
```

Junit:

```
@Test
public final void testMatchKey() {
    Assert.assertEquals("453-04430-B", HelperRegex.matchKey("453-04430-B-1"));
}
```

there is a no match found exception thrown.

I've proven my regex with "the regex coach" and it seems not broken, and matches all the teststring

[image]

Comment: I just like seeing Regex Coach 'cuz it's a Lisp app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind all that complexity. You only need one line:

```
String match = input.replaceAll(".*?([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[BL])?.*", "$1");
```

This will produce a blank string if the pattern is not found.

If it were me, I would in-line this and not even have a separare method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the group you want to retrieve with `()` and make sure your regex matches the whole string (note that group 0 is the whole string, so what you want is group 1):

```
String key = "453-04430-B-1";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d*-\\d*-[BL]).*");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(key);
if (m.matches())
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); //prints 453-04430-B
```

Comment: this solved the problem, seems theres required to build the Matcher.

Comment: @MemLeak I've never used the toMatchResult method to be honest.